# Need help to understand template function with complex typename parameters

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, enable-if

I'm examining a Stroustroup's book "C++ Programming 4th edition". And I'm trying to follow his example on matrix design.

His matrix class heavily depends on templates and I try my best to figure them out.
Here is one of the helper classes for this matrix

> A Matrix_slice is the part of the Matrix implementation that maps a
>   set of subscripts to the location of an element. It uses the idea
>   of generalized slices (§40.5.6):

```
template<size_t N>
struct Matrix_slice {
    Matrix_slice() = default; // an empty matrix: no elements
    Matrix_slice(size_t s, initializer_list<size_t> exts); // extents
    Matrix_slice(size_t s, initializer_list<size_t> exts, initializer_list<siz e_t> strs);// extents and strides
    template<typename... Dims> // N extents
    Matrix_slice(Dims... dims);


    template<typename... Dims,
    typename = Enable_if<All(Convertible<Dims,size_t>()...)>>
    size_t operator()(Dims... dims) const; // calculate index from a set of    subscripts

    size_t size; // total number of elements
    size_t start; // star ting offset
    array<size_t,N> extents; // number of elements in each dimension
    array<size_t,N> strides; // offsets between elements in each dimension
};
I
```

**Here are the lines that build up the subject of my question:**

```
template<typename... Dims,
        typename = Enable_if<All(Convertible<Dims,size_t>()...)>>
        size_t operator()(Dims... dims) const; // calculate index from a set of    subscripts
```

earlier in the book he describes how Enable_if and All() are implemented:

```
template<bool B,typename T>
using Enable_if = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;


constexpr bool All(){
    return true;
}
template<typename...Args>
constexpr bool All(bool b, Args... args)
{
    return b && All(args...);
}
```

I have enough information to understand how they work already and by looking at his Enable_if implementation I can deduce Convertible function as well:

```
template<typename From,typename To>
bool Convertible(){
    //I think that it looks like that, but I haven't found 
    //this one in the book, so I might be wrong
    return std::is_convertible<From, To>::value;
}
```

So, I can undersand the building blocks of this template function declaration
but I'm confused when trying to understand how they work altogather.
I hope that you could help

```
template<typename... Dims,
//so here we accept the fact that we can have multiple arguments like (1,2,3,4)

        typename = Enable_if<All(Convertible<Dims,size_t>()...)>>
        //Evaluating and expanding from inside out my guess will be
        //for example if Dims = 1,2,3,4,5
        //Convertible<Dims,size_t>()... = Convertible<1,2,3,4,5,size_t>() =
        //= Convertible<typeof(1),size_t>(),Convertible<typeof(2),size_t>(),Convertible<typeof(3),size_t>(),...
        //= true,true,true,true,true

        //All() is thus expanded to All(true,true,true,true,true)            
        //=true;

        //Enable_if<true>
        //here is point of confusion. Enable_if takes two tamplate arguments, 
        //Enable_if<bool B,typename T>
        //but here it only takes bool

        //typename = Enable_if(...) this one is also confusing

        size_t operator()(Dims... dims) const; // calculate index from a set of    subscripts
```

So what do we get in the end?
This construct

```
template<typename ...Dims,typename = Enable_if<true>>
size_t operator()(Dims... dims) const;
```

The questions are:

1. Don't we need the second template argument for Enable_if
2. Why do we have assignment ('=') for a typename
3. What do we get in the end?

**Update:**
You can check the code in the same book that I'm referencing here
[The C++ Programming Language 4th edition](http://mazonka.com/shared/Straustrup4th.pdf) at page 841 (Matrix Design)

Comment: This can not be a real code. `Enable_if<All(Convertible<Dims,size_t>()...)>` will trigger compiler error, since template argument can only be an expression known at compile time. A return value of `All` is not.

Comment: @SergeyA I assume he's just missing a `constexpr` in front of the function definitions.  I'm pretty sure that will make it work.

Comment: @GuyGreer, OP might. But than what else is OP missing? ;)

Comment: @SergeyA He's missing a default template parameter for the template alias `Enable_If`?  That doesn't really relate to the first comment though, so I'm not sure what you're winking at... ;)

Comment: @GuyGreer, I am trying to make a point that I can't explain how the code works when it does not. And I am not going to proofread the question for OP. But feel free to answer the question if you can.

Comment: You are right, I'm missing constexpr in the All() declaration. I also can not exactly copy it in my visual studio 2013, because it doesnt support constexpr. That's also a prob that I forgot

Answer (score 4):

This is basic SFINAE. You can read it up [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), for example.

For the answers, I'm using `std::enable_if_t` here instead of the `EnableIf` given in the book, but the two are identical:

1. As mentioned in the answer by @GuyGreer, the second template parameter of is defaulted to `void`.
2. The code can be read as a "normal" function template definition

   ```
   template<typename ...Dims, typename some_unused_type = enable_if_t<true> >
   size_t operator()(Dims... dims) const;
   ```

   With the `=`, the parameter `some_unused_type` is defaulted to the type on the right-hand side. And as one does not use the type `some_unused_type` explicitly, one also does not need to give it a name and simply leave it empty.

   This is the usual approach in C++ also found for function parameters. Check for example [`operator++(int)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith) -- one does not write `operator++(int i)` or something like that.
3. What's happening all together is SFINAE, which is an abbreviation for *Substitution Failure Is Not An Error*. There are two cases here:

   - First, if the boolean argument of `std::enable_if_t` is `false`, one gets

     ```
     template<typename ...Dims, typename = /* not a type */>
     size_t operator()(Dims ... dims) const;
     ```

     As there is no valid type on the rhs of `typename =`, type deduction fails. Due to SFINAE, however, it does not lead to a compile-time error but rather to a removal of the function from the overload set.

     The result in practice is as if the function would have not been defined.
   - Second, if the boolean argument of `std::enable_if_t` is `true`, one gets

     ```
     template<typename ...Dims, typename = void>
     size_t operator()(Dims... dims) const;
     ```

     Now `typename = void` is a valid type definition and so there is no need to remove the function. It can thus be normally used.

Applied to your example,

```
template<typename... Dims,
        typename = Enable_if<All(Convertible<Dims,size_t>()...)>>
        size_t operator()(Dims... dims) const;
```

the above means that this function exists only if `All(Convertible<Dims,size_t>()...` is `true`. This basically means the function parameters should all be integer indices (me personally, I would write that in terms of `std::is_integral<T>` however).

Comment: A couple of nitpicks (feel free to nitpick my answer too if you like :P), the type deduction failure _can_ lead to a compilation error, it just doesn't if another function overload can be found in its stead.

Comment: Also, `Convertible` is more generic than `std::is_integral` as the latter checks for an occurrence from a pre-determined list of types, whereas the former will accept user-defined types with a conversion to `std::size_t` (I'm pretty sure a conversion to any integral type will suffice, as after that a type promotion is done rather than a conversion to get a `std::size_t`).

Comment: This is a great chunk of explanation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The missing `constexpr`s notwithstanding, [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) is a template that takes two parameters, but the second one is defaulted to `void`.  It makes sense when writing up a quick alias to this to keep that convention.

Hence the alias should be defined as:

```
   template <bool b, class T = void>
   using Enable_if = typename std::enable_if<b, T>::type;
```

I have no insight into whether this default parameter is present in the book or not, just that this will fix that issue.

The assignment of a type is called a [type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) and does what it says on the tin, when you refer to the alias, you're actually referring to what it aliases.  In this case it means that when you write `Enable_if<b>`  the compiler handily expands that to `typename std::enable_if<b, void>::type` for you, saving you all that extra typing.

What you get in the end is a function that is only callable if every parameter you passed to it is convertible to a `std::size_t`.  This allows overloads of functions to be ignored if specific conditions are not met which is more a powerful technique than just matching types up for selecting what function to call.  The link for `std::enable_if` has more information on why you would want to do that, but I warn beginners that this subject gets kinda heady.

Comment: Thanks but still It's not answering 2 more questions in the topic